# How to remove u'' from python script result?

Tags: python, utf-8, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to write parsing script using python/scrapy. How can I remove [] and u' from strings in result file?

Now I have text like this:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from googleparser.items import GoogleparserItem
import sys

class GoogleparserSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "google.com"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+first+test&num=20&hl=uk&start=0",
    "http://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+second+test&num=20&hl=uk&start=0"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
       print "===START======================================================="
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       qqq = hxs.select('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
       print qqq
       print "---DATA--------------------------------------------------------"

       sites = hxs.select('/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/ol/li/h3')
       i = 1
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           try:
           item = GoogleparserItem()
           title1 = site.select('a').extract()
           title2=str(title1)
           title=remove_tags(title2)
           link=site.select('a/@href').extract()
               item['num'] = i  
           item['title'] = title
               item['link'] = link
               i= i+1
               items.append(item)
           except: 
               print 'EXCEPTION'
       return items
       print "===END========================================================="

SPIDER = GoogleparserSpider()
```

and I have result like this after running

```
python scrapy-ctl.py crawl google.com

2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [-] Log opened.
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [googleparser] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: CoreStats, CloseSpider, WebService, TelnetConsole, MemoryUsage
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [googleparser] DEBUG: Enabled scheduler middlewares: DuplicatesFilterMiddleware
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [googleparser] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloaderStats, UserAgentMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RetryMiddleware
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [googleparser] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: UrlLengthMiddleware, HttpErrorMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [googleparser] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: CsvWriterPipeline
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [-] scrapy.webservice.WebService starting on 6080
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [-] scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole starting on 6023
2010-07-25 17:44:44+0300 [google.com] INFO: Spider opened
2010-07-25 17:44:45+0300 [google.com] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+first+test&num=20&hl=uk&start=0> (referer: None)
===START=======================================================
[u'this is first test - \u041f\u043e\u0448\u0443\u043a Google']
---DATA--------------------------------------------------------
2010-07-25 17:52:42+0300 [google.com] DEBUG: Scraped GoogleparserItem(num=1, link=[u'http://www.amazon.com/First-Protector-Small-Tamora-Pierce/dp/0679889175'], title=u"[u'Amazon.com: First Test (Protector of the Small) (9780679889175 ...']") in <http://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+first+test&num=100&hl=uk&start=0>
```

and this text in file:

```
1,[u'Amazon.com: First Test (Protector of the Small) (9780679889175 ...'],[u'http://www.amazon.com/First-Protector-Small-Tamora-Pierce/dp/0679889175']
```

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, thanks a lot. ))

Comment: For anyone else who wants to remove u, I just wanted to let you know that usually there isn't a good reason to remove it. It just marks a string as unicode, but doesn't actually appear as a part of the string when you process it. For example, you can print any of the string in the list, and you can see that 'u' doesn't appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

more prettier - `print qqq.pop()`

Answer (score 6):

Replace `print qqq` with `print qqq[0]`. You get that result because `qqq` is a list.

Same problem with your text file. You have a list with one element that you're writing instead of the element within the list.

Comment: Just wondering why I got downvoted. As far as I can tell, I did answer correctly.

Comment: ?? I didn't downwoted you. But I tried your variant and it didn't work for me. Maybe I made something wrong. Anyway, I'm very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the result from `extract` is a `list`.  Try:

```
print ', '.join(qqq)
```

Answer (score 1):

The u infront of the code, purely means it's a unicode string. See the reference here. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings. The fix would be to convert your content to a string using the str() method.